# Can't open project structure in Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated `Android Studio 2.0` and Set `Use new 'Project Structure' dialog` in `Settting->Build,Execution,Deployment->Build Tools ->Gradle->Experimental`.When I tryed to open `Project Structure dialog`, It showed some error and the dialog didn't show.[image: set it]
[image: try to open]
[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 2.0 is preview version not stable so you have to work parallaly with your old android studio version please check [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/11/android-studio-20-preview.html).

Comment: I just want to slove this quesition.

Answer (score -1):

[image: click on the arrow (>)button next to Project>Package . There you can see all options are available .]
click on the arrow (>)button next to Project>Package . There you can see all options are available

Comment: Project Structure dialog is a dialog